# I have n number of file and want to remove certain names from each file, I have successfully done most of it. But there is one problem

Tags: python, replace, split, strip

I want to remove '**""**' and the **./CNODE_1/**.

Original Line : scalar per node: total_pressure                                   "./CNODE_1/F2P2FBsurfacesparallel_1.scl1"

Required Line : scalar per node: total_pressure                                   F2P2FBsurfacesparallel_1.scl1

I read the line and split it accordingly and have few lines like this in each file, so I am using **for** loop for all lines in the file

```
saved_line_split_corrected = saved_line_split[4].strip('"./CNODE_%d/"'%(i-1))
```

For i = 2, and the output is **scalar per node: total_pressure                                   F2P2FBsurfacesparallel_1.scl** i.e,**1 is removed from .scl1**.
As I have many files, For every file one or two numbers are in the .extension are being removed (eg for i = 23, .scl2 and .scl3 are just .scl and .scl)

I am not sure what is the mistake in this.
Can anyone help me with this ?

```
for i in range (1,2):
    with open("cnode_%d.encas" % (i), "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        #print(lines)
        #contents = lines
    with open("cnode_%d.encas" % (i), "w") as f:
        i=i+1
        print("%d" %(i))
        for line in lines:
            counter = counter+1
            print(counter)

            if "pressure" in line:
                saved_line = line
                print(saved_line)
                saved_line_split = saved_line.split()
                print(saved_line_split)
                saved_line_split_corrected = saved_line_split[4].strip('"./CNODE_%d/"'%(i-1))
                print(saved_line_split_corrected)
                #saved_line_split_corrected = saved_line_split_corrected_1.strip('./CNODE_%d/' %(i-1))
                #print(saved_line_split_corrected)
                saved_line_corrected = saved_line.replace(saved_line_split[4],saved_line_split_corrected)
                print(saved_line_corrected)
                saved_line_corrected = saved_line_corrected.replace('.'+saved_line_split_corrected,'.'+saved_line_split[4])
                f.write(saved_line_corrected)
                print(saved_line_corrected)
            else:
                f.write(line)
```

Comment: post the whole code

Comment: @Vulwsztyn Posted

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the line:

`saved_line_split_corrected = saved_line_split[4].strip('"./CNODE_%d/"' % (i - 1))`

I replaced it with:

`saved_line_split_corrected = saved_line_split[4].replace('./CNODE_%d/' % (i - 1), '').strip('"')`

`strip` strips all characters that you pass to it from beginning and end of line so if one of them is `(i-1)` then it gets stripped

Comment: Or `"`, or `/`, or etc.